# hPlot rCharts column and line plot

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I have a data.frame

```
       Date         Label   Number1 Number2
       1/5/14   TYPE-1  438 174
       1/5/14   TYPE-2  44  25
       1/12/14  TYPE-1  653 238
       1/12/14  TYPE-3  2   2
       1/12/14  TYPE-2  75  34
       1/19/14  TYPE-1  655 244
       1/19/14  TYPE-3  10  8
       1/19/14  TYPE-2  83  46
       1/26/14  TYPE-1  624 244
       1/26/14  TYPE-3  6   4
       1/26/14  TYPE-2  83  37
       2/2/14   TYPE-1  676 269
       2/2/14   TYPE-3  9   4
       2/2/14   TYPE-3  1   1
       2/2/14   TYPE-2  112 44
       2/9/14   TYPE-1  16  8
       2/9/14   TYPE-2  1   1
```

I want to pot this using 'hPlot' Number1 as line and Number2 as column chart in rCharts using

`hPlot(Number1+Number2~Date, data = df, type = c('line','bar'), group = c('Label'),  radius = 6)`

Comment: @Ramnath Could you help me with this?